Young Screenwriters' "Writing short" example script makes no sense to me
Could anyone please help me to understand the following:
Young Screenwriters have a course "Writing short" where they explain how to write a good script by following certain rules like "Protagonist", "Antagonist", "Objectives", "Obstacles" which are basics for the scripts to my understanding. They also show an animated short film based on a script of one of the students. Before taking the course the video made no sense to me. After taking the course all I see is the aforementioned basics applied without any logic. The obstacle the girl is facing seems artificially created by the boat not being able to speak clearly? So why would she just go with it instead of trying to ask again? What does the wizard represent there? I basically don't understand anything, not as a viewer nor as a "script writer".
Could someone please explain this video to me? Why it was chosen as an good example in the course?

This site is for discussing the craft of writing, editing, and publishing. If you want an analysis of a piece of writing such as this video's film script, you should ask it on our sibling site [Literature.SE].

It happens quite often that the help someone is given is incomprehensible to them. Maybe because the asker lacks some prior knowledge necessary to understand and apply the information they are given; maybe because the information was given in an incomprehensible manner. The latter is symbolized by the boat's mubling in the video.
It is also quite common that people do not dare to ask for clarification. Some may not want to disclose their lack of comprehension because they would feel ashamed (a common occurrence among students who don't want to appear stupid in front of their peers or teachers). Some may be afraid to raise the ire of the informant, because not every "teacher" reacts patiently to "slow" students – many become irritated and reproach those who don't understand quick enough or keep bothering them.
While the boat represents help that is freely given but incomprehensible, the wizard represents the kind of help that would be easy to give and require minimal effort (he has a shovel) but is withheld because the person holding it does not support or believe in the goals of the person asking for it. Many people encounter such attempts at diverting them from their goals, often by friends or family members who believe that a goal is unattainable or doesn't match their own goals for that person (e.g. children who want to become screenwriters instead of lawyers).
The moon is a common metaphor for the unattainable, so basically the movie tells you to follow your dreams and claims that you can realize what seems to be impossible, if only you don't let yourself be stopped by other people's doubts (the wizard) or your initial lack of understanding (the boat).

The video was chosen not because it is a good teaching example but because it was made by a student of the course and won an award. It is shown to those interested before they enroll as part of the marketing. It promises success (an award) if you enroll just like cigarette ads promise a great life if you smoke.
If and how the video is used in the course, I cannot say, but if it is supposed to illustrate the teaching and remains incomprehensible to you, you should approach your teachers and ask them for clarification (and not do like the little girl does and dig around the internet aimlessly).

Hi @Ben, thank you for the answer. It does shed a bit of light on the video, although I am not still convinced that the reasoning behind the example choice is the It is shown to those interested before they enroll as part of the marketing. But I might be too naive here
